# Set Variable in Function Loop Use In Page

Tags: php, function, global-variables

I am looking to set some variables inside a function, inside a loop. Example:

```
function setvars($POSTArray) {
   foreach ($POSTArray as $name => $var) {
      $$name = $var;
   }
}
```

I then want to use these later in the page. So I need them to work globally outside of the function down in the html part of the page.

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `$GLOBALS[]`:

```php
function setvars($POSTArray) {
   foreach ($POSTArray as $name => $var) {
      $GLOBALS[$name] = $var;
   }
}

// You can now use the variable here using its name as normal
// (no need to use the $GLOBALS[] reference)
```

Comment: Getting... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in /.../ on line 16. Line 16 is the global line.